# Calculating running time of a program (Big O Notation)

Tags: c++, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

```
void foo(float[] array, int start, int end){
    if((end-start) <=1) return;

    int x = (end-start) / 5;
    int y = 2*x;
    int z = 4*x;

    foo(array,start,start+y);
    for(index = y; index < z; index++){
        array[index]++;
    }
    foo(array, start+z, end);
}
```

I get that for loop initializations are executed N+1 times, while the inner code is executed N times so that means the time complexity would be O((N+1)*(N)) = O(n^2). But how do I calculate N in this situation? And how do I deal with the recursive call? How can I convert this information into Big O notation?

Please do not say this is a duplicate question. I understand that there are similar questions with other examples but this example is abstract to me and learning how to solve it would help me in many other situations.

Comment: O(N+1(N)) ≠ O(N²). O(N + N) = O(2N) = O(N) (since, in Big-O notation we generally ignore constants).

Comment: `x`, `y`, and `z` are not constant like in your code comments.  They are derived from `n=end-start`.

Comment: But their worst-case calculation time is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the input to `foo` is:

```
foo(array, 0, 1000)
```

So, first of all, `x` becomes 200 which is one fifth of the whole data. Then `y` and `z` become the second and the fourth [quintiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile). Note that they are still a fraction of `end - start` (1000), not constants.

The `for` goes:

```
for(index = y; index < z; index++)
```

which is from `y` to `z`. `y` was 400 (2 * 1000 / 5) and `z` was 800 (4 * 1000 / 5). So the number of times the `for` loops is 800 - 400 = 400 = (4 - 2) * 1000 / 5. Perhaps the person who analyzed this for you called it `N`, but it's quite absurd. What you do inside the loop is a simple increment which takes constant time (`O(1)`) and there is no `N` involved there!

So let's name things ourselves. I'll call the 1000 above `N`. So basically, the `for` loops 2N/5 times.

---

How about the recursions? The first recursion recurses on `start` to `start + x` (i.e. the first 2/5 of the data) and the second one recurses on `start + z` to `end` (i.e. the last 1/5 of the data).

Assuming your function takes `f(N)` time in total to calculate whatever it is doing, it can be broken down to:

```
f(N) = f(2N/5) + 2N/5 + f(N/5)
```

Now all you need is to analyze this recursive function and try to understand what would be the order.

---

While there are many ways to understand this, such as drawing a tree that shows how `f` expands and with what parameters, you can also try to find the easier upper and lower limits of the function. If they are the same, you're in luck:

```
2N/5 + 2*f(N/5) < f(n) < 2*f(2N/5) + 2N/5
```

By [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3), both limits fall in Case 3, and both limits turn out to be `θ(N)`, so your `foo` function is in fact `θ(N)`.

Another way too look at it is the following:

1. The first recursion touches the first 2N/5 of the data
2. The for loop touches the second 2N/5 of the data
3. The second recursion touches the last N/5 of the data

As you can see, each element of the array is touched once and only once. So the time complexity of the function is `θ(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Before we look at the actual Big-O of the function as a whole, let's correct your code snippet real quick.

```
// O(4 + N + 2*O(?)) = O(N + O(?))
void foo(float[] array, int start, int end){
    if((end-start) <=1) return; // O(1)

    int x = (end-start) / 5; // O(1)
    int y = 2*x; // O(1)
    int z = 4*x; // O(1)

    foo(array,start,start+y); // O(?)
    for(index = y; index < z; index++){ // O(N)
        array[index]++; // O(1)
    }
    foo(array, start+z, end); // O(?)
}
```

Now, in the base case (`end - start <= 1`), foo returns immediately, making it `O(1)`. In the second to base case, that means that this function is `O(N)` (just the `for` loop). In the third to the base case, that means that this function is `O(N + N + N) = O(3N) = O(N)`. It proceeds this way up the chain.

It's important to remember that there's some (possibly large) constant factor there that we're ignoring, but the algorithm as a whole still falls into the category of `O(N)`.

Admittedly, this method lacks rigor, but gets us a good estimate with a minimum of work.